# How I send PHP parameter/variable to JS function?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get URL parameter with PHP and send the parameter (ID) to a JS function.

This is what I tried.

PHP:

```
$param = $_GET['param']; 

if($param != "" || $param == NULL || (!empty($param))){

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'onparam($param);',
    '</script>';
}
```

JS:

```
function onparam(param) {
    $.ajax({url: "AJAX.php", data: 'id=' + param + '&switch_content=details', success: function(result){
            $("#data-table").html(result);
        }});
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}
```

I tried to put the parameter in a variable and call the JS function with it.
In the next step I tried to catch the variable in the JS function to put it in the string of "data:".

Comment: You probably just need to replace `'onparam($param);',` by `"onparam($param);",` (double quotes instead of simple)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: wha.. just have a .js file with an ajax call inside to the PHP?

Comment: @gogaz's solution is probably the right one, but what result are you getting?

Comment: I changed it but it still dont work.

Comment: Also, just `if(!empty($param)){`

Comment: Is `param` a string?

Comment: This is out of the scope of the question but it's pretty easy to parse GET parameters in Javascript nowadays

Comment: Assume you also need          `"onparam('$param');",` https://3v4l.org/iZd4N

Comment: (You know that JavaScript has access to the URL as well, right? And that [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) gives easy access to GET parameters …)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use double quote instead of singles quotes (as suggested by gogaz). You also want to put quotation marks around the variable if it's a string.

One more thing - You can remove `$param != "" || $param == NULL` as both `""` & `null` are considered to be empty. I am assuming you mean `$param != "" && $param != NULL` here, if not, just ignore. But that may also be causing the issue if $param is null.

```
$param = $_GET['param']; 

if(!empty($param)) {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>",
        "onparam('$param');",
    "</script>";
}
```